# How to handle updates from an continuous process pipe in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, logging, fedora

I am trying to follow log files in Perl on Fedora but unfortunately, Fedora uses `journalctl` to read binary log files that I cannot parse directly. This, according to my understanding, means I can only read Fedora's log files by calling `journalctl`.

I tried using [`IO::Pipe`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Pipe) to do this, but the problem is that `$p->reader(..)`  waits until `journalctl --follow` is done writing output (which will be never since `--follow` is like `tail -F`) and then allows me to print everything out which is not what I want. I would like to be able to set a callback function to be called each time a new line is printed to the process pipe so that I can parse/handle each new log event.

```
use IO::Pipe;

my $p = IO::Pipe->new();
$p->reader("journalctl --follow"); #Waits for process to exit

while (<$p>) {
  print;
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly when I use .e.g. `tail -f messages` instead of `journalctl` (which I don't have). Did you try `journalctl --follow --no-pager`?

Comment: The `--no-pager` is a red herring, as any sensible Unix program will only call a pager when its `stdout` is a `tty`. I tried your program on my Jolla telephone (which has `journalctl`) and it works as expected. Whatever is wrong is not in your code!

Comment: @HansLub That works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `journalctl` is working like `tail -f`. If this is correct, a simple `open` should do the job:

```
use Fcntl; # Import SEEK_CUR

my $pid = open my $fh, '|-', 'journalctl --follow'
    or die "Error $! starting journalctl";
while (kill 0, $pid) {
    while (<$fh>) {
        print $_; # Print log line
    }
    sleep 1; # Wait some time for new lines to appear
    seek($fh,0,SEEK_CUR); # Reset EOF
}
```

`open` opens a filehandle for reading the output of the called command: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

`seek` is used to reset the EOF marker: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html Without reset, all subsequent `<$fh>` calls will just return EOF even if the called script issued additional output in the meantime.

`kill 0,$pid` will be true as long as the child process started by `open` is alive.

You may replace `sleep 1` by `usleep` from [`Time::HiRes`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::HiRes) or `select undef,undef,undef,$fractional_seconds;` to wait less than a second depending on the frequency of incoming lines.

[AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent) should also be able to do the job via it's [`AnyEvent::Handle`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent::Handle).

**Update:**

Adding `use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";` at the beginning and `waitpid $pid, WNOHANG)` to the outer loop would also detect (and reap) a zombie `journalctl` process:

```
while (kill(0, $pid) and waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) != $pid) {
```

A daemon might also want to check if `$pid` is still a child of the current process (`$$`) and if it's still the original `journalctl` process.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? I barely know perl, but this looks extremely wrong to me. At least perl as provided in fedora (5.22.1-351.fc23.x86_64) will not reap zombies and signalling a zombie with 0 works just fine, so this is an infinite loop. If it was reaping zombies, it would race against something possibly reusing the pid. Maybe perl's pipe handling is odd, but 1. SEEK_CUR should not work 2. there should be no data left and no possibility of new data once the read loop is done. If the other end is still open, the procss would block in the kernel. So that 'sleep 1' is useless.

Comment: Please RTFM for the commands, all of them are linked from the answer. Sure, `kill 0` is not fail-proof, but sufficient for most cases. As the manual states, Perl's `<$fh>` reads until EOF and returns undef/empty list afterwards. The `seek SEEK_CUR` resets the EOF marker. The process would go to 100% CPU (EOF -> seek -> EOF -> seek) if no new data arrives. It's one way of solving the question, but Perl is TIMTOWTDY: Using AnyEvent or `select` would be more professional, but also more complex.

Comment: But if the zombie is not reaped (and in my case it is not), the loop is infinite. Do you have a version which reaps on its own? Given your edit adding waitpid I'm additionally confused about your reply. For reading, so-called EOF is detected with read syscall returning 0. This is not going to happen even if the pipe is empty as long as someone has the other end open. Maybe perl has a bug related to this (does it?) and spuriously sets EOF on its handles, but I see no evidence for this claim. tl;dr the outer while loop looks unnecessary and wrong. can you show a case where it is needed?

Comment: See the comment above and the comments in the answer. Perl has it's own buffering for I/O and it's no bug if something behaves as expected and documented. Perl is *not* a pure wrapper for kernel syscalls (actually `sysopen`, `sysread`, `syswrite` and `sysseek` exist as pure wrapper functions with all problems of these syscalls).

Comment: So where it is documented fh can get EOF with a pipe while it is still possible there will be data to read? Meanwhile I checked http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens and there is an example reading stuff from a pipe and there is no mention about the need to clear eof or re-read stuff. Looking at seek manual it seems you just cargo-culted a snippet intended for use with regular files and applied it to a pipe.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html says *A WHENCE of 1 (SEEK_CUR ) is useful for not moving the file position. [...] This is also useful for applications emulating tail -f . Once you hit EOF on your read and then sleep for a while, you (probably) have to stick in a dummy seek() to reset things. The seek doesn't change the position, but it does clear the end-of-file condition on the handle, so that the next <FILE> makes Perl try again to read something.*

Comment: Again, where it is documented fh can get EOF with a pipe while it is still possible there will be data to read? The thing you quoted sounds like it only applies to regular files. The sleep in the code sample also strongly hints this - it is there to give something else a chance to add input. Reading from an empty pipe blocks in the kernel, so sleeping does not add anything. Strictly speaking it is possible perl sets EOF when it should not, but that's extremely unlikely and would be very odd. In fact it's quite unclear what criteria could be used to incorrectly set it.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on read stub in glibc and in backtrace I see it is called from PerlIOBuf_fill. The only code setting EOF is either when fd is incorrect (closed?) or when read returns 0. read on a pipe is not going to return 0 if the other end is open. It may be i missed something here, but given how weird such EOF would be in the first place, I'm confident the outher loop in your code serves no purpose. http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/perlio.c

Comment: This code doesn't work.  The first problem is opens a pipe for writing to (`|-`) not reading from (`-|`).  If you fix that, you'll discover that, as noted above, `<$fh>` blocks when there's no further output rather than returning EOF, so the outer loop is redundant.  If you want to check if there's any data to read without blocking, you'll need to switch to `sysread`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to `journalctl`, but if you avoid `IO::Pipe` and open the piped output directly then the data will not be buffered

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $follow_fh, '-|', 'journalctl --follow' or die $!;

print while <$follow_fh>;
```